# Change App Domain Using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

I have hosted a app on pagoda box, my app installation has a url like wm-app.pagodabox.com. I added a DNS alias for eg: app.com which gave me a IP to point my A record to. I did that, it works just fine.

The problem is now that I go to app.com it redirects the domain to wm-app.pagodabox.com.

Pagoda-Box says that I can use simple apache URL rewrites to fix this. I have never understood the rewrites. I have only used it for removing index.php from my URLs, code for which is widely available online. I wan't any user visiting my site to see app.com instead of wm-app.pagodabox.com

Here is what I have so far (I have a feeling I am wrong):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wm-app.pagodabox.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I appreciate all the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There where some minor errors in your code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wm-app\.pagodabox\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.com/$1 [R=301]

# might work but not very likely
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^app\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
```

This should almost work under normal circumstances, but it your case there is already something doing the redirect the other way around. So my guess it the above code, combined with the existing redirect, will result in a redirect-tennis-competition (redirect back and forth)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what do I do about the redirect loop. Can't I just show the domain as app.com instead of a redirect, like we do when removing the index.php from URLs. I'm not sure how that works, perhaps that's a redirect too. Is it?

Comment: First of all, do you get a loop with the above code? Secondly; it kind of depends on how you host has implemented the redirect/alias.

Comment: In the above edit do I have to write both the rewrite rules or try both separately from each other?

Comment: I got in touch with pagodabox. They say it can be mentioned inside the app as baseurl. Thanks for your help anyway. They just have bad bad documentation.

Comment: You can still use the top rule for the redirect. Good luck.

Comment: I can't, it starts the redirecting back and forth. Thanks! It is fixed with the baseurl of the app. I have finally done it.